# jQuery animation in select

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want an input system like android. The problem is that I'm not able to do the same animation on the `<select>` element.

Could anyone help me?

```js
$('.form_campos').on('focus blur', function(e) {
  $(this).parents('.form-group').toggleClass('focused', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value.length > 0));
}).trigger('blur');

$('.form_campos_box').on('focus blur', function(e) {
  $(this).parents('.box').toggleClass('focused', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value.length > 0));
}).trigger('blur');
```

```css
    body {
      font-family: Verdana;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    
     .form-group {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      height: 45px;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 2px;
    }
    
    .control-label {
      opacity: 0.4;
      pointer-events: none;
      position: absolute;
      transform: translate3d(5px, 22px, 0) scale(1);
      transform-origin: left top;
      transition: 240ms;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    
    .form-group.focused .control-label {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: scale(0.75);
    }
    
    .form_campos {
      height: 20px;
      color: #484848;
      z-index: 1;
      align-self: flex-end;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding: 5px;
      outline: none;
      border-color: #484848;
      border-style: solid;
      border-bottom-width: 1px;
      border-top-width: 0;
      border-right-width: 0;
      border-left-width: 0;
      background: transparent;
    }
    
    .form_campos:hover,
    .form_campos:focus {
      border-color: #1E90FF;
    }
    
    .form_campos_numeros {
      width: 123px;
    }
    /* SELECT */
    
    .select {
      font-size: 15px;
      height: 31px;
      color: #484848;
      border-radius: 0px;
      border-color: #484848;
      border-style: solid;
      border-bottom-width: 1px;
      border-top-width: 0;
      border-right-width: 0;
      border-left-width: 0;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: #ffffff;
      outline: none;
      margin-top: 14px;
      background: transparent;
      padding-right: 20px;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    select::-ms-expand {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .select:hover,
    .select:focus {
      border-color: #1E90FF;
      border-style: solid;
      border-bottom-width: 1px;
      border-top-width: 0;
      border-right-width: 0;
      border-left-width: 0;
    }
    
    .control-label-select {
      position: absolute;
      transform-origin: left top;
      opacity: 1;
      transform: scale(0.75);
    }
    
    .form-group-select {
      position: relative;
      height: 45px;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 2px;
    }
    
    .form-group-select:after {
      content: "\279C";
      color: #484848;
      transform: rotate(90deg);
      right: 8px;
      top: 22px;
      position: absolute;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    /* FIM SELECT */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form-group-select'>
  <label class='control-label-select'>CENTRO DE CUSTO</label>
  <select name='banco' class='select form_campos_numeros'>
    <option value='0'></option>
    <option value='1'>custo</option>
    <option value='1'>custo</option>
  </select>
</div>


<div class='form-group'>
  <label class='control-label' for='numParcelas'>PARCELAS*</label>
  <input type='text' class='form_campos form_campos_numeros' id='numParcelas' name='numParcelas'>
</div>
```

PS: I want to make the animation of the select, the same as the input.

Comment: Could you include more code? What are you trying to do? Be more specific so we can help you.

Comment: all the code in this link jsFiddle

Comment: you are attaching an event to the `form_campos_box` class, but you don't have this class anywhere in your html

Comment: Thanks! This really cleared up what you wanted to do! Also, are you writing in Portuguese?

Comment: @EricPhillips Yes he is. He has an input at the bottom with that class.

Comment: @EricPhillips Actually never mind I misread your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you exactly want to do.
But I'm sure that the correct way is used as a div designed as select. The component that you do not make it, for example :

https://select2.github.io/examples.html

it is much more scalable than a simple select. And full browser support, specially for list of variable in select.

Comment: Browsers notoriously have little suitable support for really customize no selects. To get a drop down, it sounded  like you are going to want to "fake it" and come up with a solution that acts like a select, but is not. Select2 is an EXCELLENT package and I'd highly recommend it. Sounds like it would be perfect for what you are trying to achieve.